Charge distribution in two concentric conducting shells connected by a thin wire

Above is the content of the problem in the title and I'm confused about the solution. I'm not sure whether it is correct or not. The two shells are conducting and connected, so the difference in electric potential between the inner and the outer sphere has to be equal zero. With simple calculations we can conclude:
$$\vec{E}(\vec{r}) = \frac{Q_{\text{enc}}}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2} = \frac{q_1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 r^2} \hat{r}$$
$$\int_a^b \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{l} = \frac{q_1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int_a^b \frac{1}{r^2} \hat{r} dr = \frac{q_1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \left( -\frac{1}{r} \right) \Bigg|_a^b \hat{r} = \frac{q_1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \left( \frac{1}{a} - \frac{1}{b} \right) \hat{r} = \frac{q_1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \frac{a - b}{ab} \hat{r}$$
$$\Delta V = 0 \implies \int_b^a \vec{E} \cdot d\vec{l} = 0 \implies q_1 = 0$$
The calculations suggest, that the charge on the inner sphere should be equal to zero. Is it correct and what's the explanation? Because if there were any charge on the inner sphere, it would create an electric field inside the conductor and it is contradictory with the definition of conductor. Is it that simple and is it the satisfactory explanation? What would happen if before the connection of the spheres there was some charge on the inner sphere? What force would pull them out to the outer sphere?

It does not matter if the wire is thin or thick, just take it very very thick so you have just one thick sphere, do you sie why the inner part has no charge.

So we're making the wire so thick, we are left with one thick shell? Than the charge accumulates only on the outer surface, because there is no charge inside the cavity of the conductor?

As soon as a charge is put on the inner spherical shell an electric field is produced which in turn means there is a potential gradient.
Any conductor connected between the inner and outer conducting shells with a potential difference across it will have a current passing through it due to the coulomb forces between charges until the potential difference across the conductor is zero when there is no charge on the inner shell.
